# ProgressBar dentro de un control personalizado no se actualiza correctamente VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, progressbar

Estoy creando un control personalizado que lo que pretende es hacer una barra de progreso, de modo que pueda definir una cantidad de procesos, y que además cada uno de esos procesos tenga asignada una proporción diferente de la barra barra de proceso, además de que cada proceso podría eventualmente no llenarse en la misma cantidad de pasos, y decidí dejar esto en un UserControl que contuviera toda esta lógica.
Este UserControl tiene 2 label (uno que dice "Estado de Avance" y otro que muestra el avance como un porcentaje) y un progressbar.
Además tengo otra clase (General), en la que tengo 2 funciones cargar_barra y descargar_barra, que crean y destruyen un objeto del usercontrol definido antes y lo agregan o quitan de la coleccion de controles del formulario (que para ambas funciones se recibe como parámetro de la función.

Finalmente tengo un formulario simple con un botón que lo único que hace es ejecutar un código (a modo de prueba del UserControl)

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim barra As ProgressShow
        barra = general.cargar_barra(Me)
        barra.inicializar(5)
        For i = 1 To 5
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000 * 2)
            barra.continua_proceso()
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000 * 0.5)
        Next
        general.descargar_barra(Me)
    End Sub
```

Todo parece funcionar bien, sin embargo, el label con el porcentaje de avance se actualiza correctamente con el porcentaje de cada vuelta del ciclo, sin embargo la barra de avance del progressbar se queda atras una vuelta del ciclo (label 20% progressbar: 0,label 40% progressbar 20 y asi ...)

Yo creo que el problema puede estar en la función dibujar_status, en donde calculo el valor que debe tener la barra según su estado de avance, intenté dejar con estas lineas pero aun así siempre la barra se queda una vuelta atrás en el ciclo

```
    barra1.Value = CInt(valor_mostrar)
    barra1.Refresh()
    porcent.Text = Format(valor_mostrar / 100, "##0.00%")
    Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()
    Thread.Sleep(50)
```

Creo que dejar todo el codigo en mi post puede ser algo molesto, así que les dejo un proyecto de Visual Studio 2010 con el proyecto funcionando (quite el codigo que no era necesario para el ejemplo) [Fuentes del Ejemplo](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bw9Sz8q1mLNEWnIzWEJGdVFqUTQ)

Si alguien pudiera decirme como solucionar el problema, se lo agradecería mucho, en una de esas la solución sería un método totalmente diferente, así acepto otras ideas, saludos.

Comment: Ya intentas hacerlo con Hilos??? si hay un proceso (ciclo corriendo el progress bar tiende a bloquearse)

Comment: Implementé los hilos para el ejemplo, tal como Rastalovely recomienda, y funciona correctamente, el problema es que el proceso real que debo dejar en segundo plano es una consulta a una base de datos de varios minutos, y no tengo como lanzar el evento progresschanged, o al menos no se como hacerlo para que la ventana no parezca pegada... así que no sé muy bien que puedo hacer en ese caso